# Delete Button Frame size

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I implement CommitEditingStyle for UITableView. But Delete Button is not look good as shown below.

[image]

I also try to resize button Frame as follow but not working

```
-(void) layoutSubviews
{
NSMutableArray *subviews = [self.subviews mutableCopy];
UIView *subV = subviews[0];
[subviews removeObjectAtIndex:0];
CGRect f = subV.frame;
f.size.height = 70; // Here you set height of Delete button
subV.frame = f;
}
```

**Help me to display good UI**

Comment: this is your cell's height which is currently shown in above image?

Comment: DO you use custom cell with auto layout?

Comment: Why don't you add a small delete inside the cell yourself? consider options like [this](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-oqnztml9sfk/U8FGzFBicoI/AAAAAAAAE3E/eTAOhT8Map4/s1600/delete+multiple+at+once+photos+from+iPhone.jpg)

Comment: @ChetanPrajapati, yes this is the cell height

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

}

-(NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewRowAction *blockUser = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Pause" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
                                   {
                                       // some operation
                                    // you also can change Text like i have done PAUSE
                                   }];

blockUser.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    return @[blockUser];
}
```

Change color whatever you want and also text if you...
By clearing color this will match with your table. and also you can set matched color with your tableview and by setting alpha value you can achieve this.

Comment: have you removed other methods that effect the tableviewcell?

Comment: i have made this for me and works well too. did checked with debug point? the method is calling or not on indextPath you are made swipe

Comment: No this method is not getting called

Comment: finally called.. sorry i forgot to copy another method

Comment: copy 3rd method which is added between 2 methods

Comment: this is already added in my code... You said previously that  
"i have made this for me and works well too"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82816/discussion-between-chetan-prajapati-and-user2526811).